# Authorization Token Value

Tags: php, oauth, authorization

How can I get the access token value from this URL?

http://4fb.in/skt-seesmic/auth.php#access_token=IkD85bV-iUgflTSd0KNbrs_Z4IApLpgVjA5dDLH9nhf7V-WI

Comment: regular expressions or simply split it with equal sign = and you will get token

Comment: we have to find out from URL. This is not just a string. Please provide php functions to get this.

Comment: $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  can help in php and document.url in javascript

Comment: $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] return null value. I think this is a authorized token value that is read only

Comment: The hash component of the url is never accessible from server-side. The only way you can access hash components is in javascript using location.hash

Answer (score 1):

On server end, the hash parameter of the url is not sent.

So, in order to process the hash part, in the above file, you can send it through javascript: (below example uses jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var auth=(window.location.hash.split('='))[1];
    $.ajax({
        url:'processing_php_file?token='+auth,
        success:function(response){
            //Processed.
        }
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var auth=(window.location.hash.split('='))[1];
    window.location='processing_php_file?token='+auth;
});
```

Then, in the processing file, you can access this value as `$_GET['token']`.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP you can use:
`parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);`

In javascript:
`alert(window.location.hash);`

Comment: The url is not static one here.